# WebStorm ecmaScript6 Почему не работает

Tags: webstorm

Выставил в настройках webstopm синтаксис ecmaScript6, но он подчеркивает красным все const, let и прочее.
Подскажите, что делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: настройки jshint смотри

Comment: Еееееее!!! Спасибо большое!!! Теперь красота!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как мне здорово посоветовал Алексей Шиманский [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/Алексей-Шиманский](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)
Действительно, надо смотреть jshint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]